# How to hide scrollbar in v-textarea?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to hide scrollbar in v-textarea?

While this works on simple textbox, but in v-textarea doing this does not work:

```
<v-textarea class="hide-scrollbar"/>
<style>
.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.hide-scrollbar textarea {overflow-y:hidden}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide Scrollbars But Keep Functionality

```
 // Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }

// Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.hide-scrollbar {
   -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
   scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

Hide Scrollbars and Functionality

```
.hide-scrollbar{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```